# Rearranging JavaScript string components

Tags: javascript

Can I write a function that takes in a string made up of a number or "pairs" separated by "|" characters and produces an object as shown below? Each pair has its two components separated internally with commas.

Example:

```
objectify("a,dog|b,cat|z,rat")  -->  {a: "dog", b: "cat", z: "rat"}
objectify("one,uno|two,dos")    -->  {one: "uno", two: "dos"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. Just give it a try, and search for answers to the parts that you don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function objectify(str) {
    var obj = {},
        arr = str.split('|');
    for (i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        var parts = arr[i].split(',');
        obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVp5A/)

Create an empty object, split the string on `|` and iterate over the parts, split again on comma, and use the result as key/value pairs in the object, and return the object when done.

Comment: This is why people think of StackOverflow as a code writing service. And why are you using `new Object()` instead of `{}`?

Comment: Care to give an explanation?

Comment: @IHateLazy - does it matter if I use new Object, and if so why ?

Comment: I was asking you, I'm not the one complaining ?

Comment: I was asking you a question.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis: I don't think that code needs any explanation. Are there parts you don't understand?

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe there are parts that OP doesn't understand.

Comment: @IHateLazy - to me they are exactly the same, that's why I was asking what the difference was, since you are implying I should'nt use new Object ?

Comment: @Bergi Before the explanation it was exactly as I Hate Lazy mentioned - using SO as a code-writing service, and a cheap source of points for the answerer. Now, with the explanation, I think it's a good answer and gives the OP enough info to learn from.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis - Me likes cheap points ?

Comment: It's unnecessarily verbose syntax. But I was still asking why, though it doesn't matter now since you updated.

Comment: @IHateLazy - new Object is great syntax, makes it clear what's going on, and I hate lazy, so I often type stuff just for fun? As for SO being a code writing service, it would be awfully quiet here if all the questions where someone asks for help to (re)write some code dissapeared, and only questions regarding the conundrums and quirks of the language was allowed ?

Comment: `new Object()` is no more clear than `{}`. Both require a knowledge of what the syntax accomplishes. OP didn't ask for *help*. Asking for help implies that OP is actually trying and needs assistance. There are plenty of people who do ask for help, and a few that ask for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectify (str) {
    var pairs = str.split("|"),
        res = {};
    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
        var parts = pairs[i].split(",");
        res[parts.shift()] = parts.join(",");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Check out [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) functions.